# When the checkbox is changed at the line item level (not the batch line item level, just the main one), then all the batch line items change too

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When the “Use Again” checkbox is changed at the line item level (not the batch line item level, just the main one), then all the batch line items change too.

When the “Use Again” checkbox is changed at the batch line item level, then only that one batch line item checkbox is affected.

```
{
  /*Use Again*/
}

{
  values.transactions.goodsMovements.transactionItems[index].transactionType ===
    "2" &&
    useAgain === 200 && (
      <>
        <td>
          <MyCheckbox1
            id={`transactions.goodsMovements.transactionItems[${index}].transactionLineItems[${i}].useAgain`}
            name={`transactions.goodsMovements.transactionItems[${index}].transactionLineItems[${i}].useAgain`}
          />
          {tlItems.expanded &&
            tlItems.batchSplits.batchSplitLineItems &&
            tlItems.batchSplits.batchSplitLineItems.length > 0 &&
            tlItems.batchSplits.batchSplitLineItems.map((bd, j) => (
              <div>
                <MyCheckbox1
                  id={`transactions.goodsMovements.transactionItems[${index}].transactionLineItems[${i}].batchSplits.batchSplitLineItems[${j}].useAgain`}
                  name={`transactions.goodsMovements.transactionItems[${index}].transactionLineItems[${i}].batchSplits.batchSplitLineItems[${j}].useAgain`}
                />
              </div>
            ))}
        </td>
      </>
    );
}
```

[image: result image]

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what `MyCheckbox1` is in your code. You need 3 changes to meet your requirements.

1. Add a `checked` property explicitly for both the parent checkbox and checkboxes of subitems/children to indicate whether the checkbox is checked. Like

```
<MyCheckbox1
  id=....
  name=....
  checked={IS_USE_AGENT_CHECKED}
/>
```

`IS_USE_AGENT_CHECKED` is a state for each checkbox(both for the parent and for children). You need to handle the value `IS_USE_AGENT_CHECKED` in your code like the following steps.

2. Handle the `onClick` event of the checkbox of the parent item, like

```
<MyCheckbox1
  id=....
  name=....
  checked={IS_USE_AGENT_CHECKED}
  onClick={FUNCTION_TO_HANDLE_THE_EVENT}
/>
```

I have no idea about the event name of your `MyCheckbox1`, it should be the equivalence to `onChange` or `onClick` of , which can be triggered when the state of the checkbox is changed. In `FUNCTION_TO_HANDLE_THE_EVENT`, if the `checked` state is true, set all children's `IS_USE_AGENT_CHECKED` true. if it is false, set all children's `IS_USE_AGENT_CHECKED` false.

3. Handle the `onClick` event of the checkbox of the children, like

```
<MyCheckbox1
  id=....
  name=....
  checked={IS_USE_AGENT_CHECKED}
  onClick={FUNCTION_TO_HANDLE_THE_EVENT}
/>
```

In this `FUNCTION_TO_HANDLE_THE_EVENT`, change `IS_USE_AGENT_CHECKED` of the current item.

Comment: Thanks .. I have added these functionalities and it worked